# Does the local storage is maintained even after the app has been updated?

Tags: cordova, storage, local

I am creating an app with PhoneGap
if my app update App Store 
Does the value of local storage is maintained?
localStorage.val = "myName" 
app store update 
localStorage.val = ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, local Storage is maintained upon app updates. You only lose it if the user deletes caches, or the app is unistalled

Comment: On iOS local storage of a Cordova app may be wiped by the OS if the device is low on storage space

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you update the app the local storage will be maintained.

Deleting & Installing the app will result in loss of local storage data.